# undefined async handler using sinon.stub()

Tags: node.js, events, aws-lambda, sinon

I know it's something obvious that I'm missing but I'm trying to write unit tests using mocha, chai and sinon for an async handler that's referencing another async service. Here's the code for what I'm dealing with:

authenticateService.js

```
module.exports = (() => {
    ...
    async authenticate(username, password) {
        const isValid = await validCreds(username)
        if (!isValid) {
            throw Error(`invalid_credentials`)
        }
        return isValid
    }
}
```

authenticateHandler.js

```
module.export.handler = {
    async (event) => {
        const auth = await authenticate(username, password)
        if (auth) {
            // do things
        }
        return {statusCodes.OK}
    }
}
```

unit test

```
describe(`Admin Module`, () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        sinon.stub(authenticateService.prototype, "authenticate")
            .callsFake(() => Promise.resolve({status:200}))
        
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        authenticationService.restore()
    })

    describe(`test auth`, () => {
        it(`Receives GET event expects statusCode 200`, async () => {
            const event = {
                httpMethod: `POST`,
                resourcePath: `/admin/authentications`,
                body: {
                    username: `fizz@email.com`,
                    password: `buzz`,
                    recaptchaToken: `some_token`
                },
            }
            
            expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200)
        })
    })
```

I tried setting the following:

- setting it in a sandbox
- using `yields`, `resolve`, `return` and could not figure out how to stub it correctly
- tried mocking the nested authenticateService, mocking the handler and mocking both

I keep getting `Error: Trying to stub property 'authenticate' of undefined` so I know it must not be instantiating the service correctly. Frankly it seems like a simple thing but I just cannot figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Is `authenticateService` a class or just named export some functions?

Comment: ah sorry, I updated the description. It's part of the object that I export